# Get image url from RegEx

Tags: regex

I have a img tag which i want to get only the URL, i mean, the content within the src property.

The string is:

```
<img src="http://preview.turbosquid.com/Preview/2014/05/18__03_00_00/0.jpg9719119e-13a7-4a25-8544-b966ea37e300Original.jpg" data-width="1200" data-height="1200" data-turntable="0" itemprop="image" style="top: 0px; left: 0px; max-height: none; max-width: none; height: 100%; width: auto; cursor: default;"/>
```

and the regex is:

```
<img src="(.*?)".*?itemprop="image".*?\/>
```

The source has several items and need to get only the first one.

[Here is the example](https://regex101.com/r/qA5dB7/1)

What's wrong?

Comment: @Michelle added the info.

Comment: Have you tried your regex on your input string? It works properly. Look [here](https://regex101.com/r/mY4pO6/1)

Comment: Your example html code does not contain a single image that start with the `src` attribute and has a `itemprop` attribute. Therefore your regex cannot match.

Comment: If by "The source has several items and need to get only the first one" you mean you only want to retrieve the first match of the regex, many libraries allow you to do this, but it will vary greatly based on the library (we'll need to know which one you're using, and you should probably separate that out into a different question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this regex will give you the results you're trying for: `<img src="([^"]*)".*\/>`

See a modification to your example at https://regex101.com/r/qA5dB7/2

Answer (score 2):

Basically what Joe said except this one is a little simpler and able to handle more complicated img tags, for example ones that contain other attributes or ones that are not self-closing.

`<img.+?src="(.+?)".*?>`